# Artifact URL on Nexus with Basic Auth

Tags: basic-authentication, nexus

I have two Nexus instances `2.0` and `2.11.4-01`. On the older one, when browsing to the URL (using a desktop browser):

```
https://nexus.example.com/content/repositories/company-releases/com/company/projectname/projectname-web/1.6.1-RC2/projectname-web-1.6.1-RC2.war
```

prompts for username and password with a `Basic-Auth` which is just what I want. I tried to accomplish the same on the newer version of Nexus and the browser does not prompt for username and password. Instead a page with the following message is displayed:

> Access Denied
>   Please login before attempting further requests.

The "login" is linked to authentication page on the Nexus UI. This is bad in my case because I am sending an artifact URL to the customer and she/he only need to provide username and password and the artifact is downloaded. I cannot now instruct all of them to use the UI login and navigate to the artifact.

Is something wrongly configured on the newer version of my Nexus instance? Or maybe something changed in that area between these versions I have?

**Edit**

I realized that CURL is getting the following response header:

```
WWW-Authenticate: BASIC realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager"
```

And desktop browsers do not. I faked the User-Agent in my Chrome browser and I got prompted for username and password. Nice! Now how to configure Nexus to always return this header?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this was a change in behavior a while back. If you have disabled anonymous access this URL will not be reachable until the user is logged in. Clearly, you can see that this is a security issue the other way around.

If they have access to your Nexus (you've provided them the necessary credentials), and they cannot browse to this URL, then you need to grant them the `UI: Base UI Privileges`.

**Update:**

Based on your edited comment, it seems like you may be hitting an issue we reported to Sonatype a while ago. Have a look at these two links:

- [How do I enable WWW-Authenticate headers for content 401 responses](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465078-How-do-I-enable-WWW-Authenticate-headers-for-content-401-responses)
- The associated JIRA ([NEXUS-6786](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-6786))

You beat me to it, while I was writing my reply, but yeah -- you need to set the following property in your `nexus.properties`:

```
nexus.browserdetector.disable=true
```

This was supposed to be a temporary workaround, related to changes in the behavior of their UI, but a some other people complained as well and I guess it stuck around.

Also, please bare in mind that Sonatype don't really recommend setting this, as it can break the behavior of the UI and keep you logged in forever (as quoted below):

"The side effect of disabling browser detection using the property in this article may include:

- Creating more than one session in a web browser for the same user
- Multiple login prompts for the same web browser user
- Inability to share the same http session for content and UI requests to Nexus
- Inability to logout and end all browser initiated sessions in a real web browser. This could be a security risk in some environments

Basically you likely will introduce session vulnerabilities in the Nexus UI and create confusion amongst your Nexus UI users."

Comment: The thing is that I cannot bother them with UI, just make the browser prompt for username and password and let them download an artifact if the credentials are correct for the repository they are trying to access. Is that possible?

Comment: Well, you will need to create a new role which has the `Read` and `View` privileges granted for that repository and then assign this role to the users.

Comment: But the actual question is regarding the authentication method not authorization. I want to be prompted for username and password as soon as I browse to the artifact URL and have this artifact returnd in the browser when credentials provided are correct for that repository.

All I want is to prompt for username and password from the browser and not redirect the customer to the UI.

Comment: The authentication method for resolving and deploying artifacts is always HTTP Basic, regardless of whether you're using a browser or `curl`. Your issue appears to be that you've disabled the anonymous access for this repository and therefore need to set up authentication and authorization properly.

Comment: I've added "Anonymous access" in server settings and added anonymous user. When I navigate (in the web browser) to the artifact URL the "Access Denied" message (with link to UI login page) still appears instead of prompting me for username and password.

Comment: You may have to restart Nexus (if you haven't done so already, of course). Also, make sure you wipe your cookies and credentials for Nexus in your browser. Alternatively, if this doesn't work, you can always join the HipChat channel for Nexus, where there's always somebody on support and you're likely to get a first-hand answer (see https://www.hipchat.com/gW26B2y2Z).

Comment: I realized that Nexus' response headers are different basing on the user User-Agent. I have edited the question. Do you know how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

I had to add the following setting to nexus.properties:

```
nexus.browserdetector.disable=true
```

And restart the Nexus. Now I get prompted for username and password when navigating with a desktop browser.

Comment: You beat me to it, while I was updating my answer! :D Glad to hear it fixed for you.